# Are flags set when AND operation in x86 is done?

Tags: assembly, x86

Suppose

```
andl %ecx %edx
```

is carried out, with the above assembly code in GAS syntax. Would this code set ZF/SF/PF flags using the AND result? Or would this code just AND two operands and do nothing about flags?

I know there is TEST and CMP instructions that set flags, but the code would be shorter if I can just use AND to set flags.

Comment: Syntax doesn't set any flags. See the manual for what the corresponding instruction does.

Comment: @harold I edited my title. Thanks for info.

Comment: Indeed, Intel's manuals (to which you can find a link on the [x86] tag info page) lists **Flags affected** for every instruction. Just look it up there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a piece of information which is trivially easy to look up in the relevant documentation.

Comment: @Michael :  IMHO, a better response to OP is to provide a link to the Intel or AMD docs.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I pointed to the x86 tag info page in my first comment. There's a link to Intel's manual there. Even without Intel's manual, the answer to this question could be found in less than a minute simply by googling for "x86 instruction set".

Comment: @Michael:  OK, I see you tried.   But I doubt a new SO user would have understood how to look there.  I'm an old user, and I didn't really see when I read you comment the first time;  I need the urge of your last comment to go back and read it again and with your hint it sank in (yet I know this, just never use it).   I think that is too obscure.  The web has links for a reason. (OP: he means "click on the colored [x86] tag in your question, then click on "learn more").

Answer (score 2):

Flags will be affected. In fact, just about any instruction that performs some arithmetic/bitwise/logical operation will modify the flags register.

I suggest you read the *Intel Developer's Manual* to find this information. Most, if not all, questions about the x86 architecture and instructions can be answered by using it.

The `AND` instruction leaves the AF flag undefined, clears the CF and OF flags, sets PF if the low byte of the result has odd parity, sets SF if the result is negative (viewed as two's complement), and sets ZF if the result is zero.

Comment: More specifically the sign flag (`SF`) will be set if-and-only-if the most significant bit of the result is set, the zero flag (`ZF`) iff the whole result is zero, and the parity flag (`PF`) set iff the number of set bits in the least-significant byte is odd.

Comment: As I just painfully learned, one of the few exceptions to this is the `not` instruction which does not set flags...